# making seo/canonicals urls without mod-rewrite on lamp

Tags: lamp, seo

i have a hosting company that does not allow .htaccess (mod-rewrite is disabled) on linux, php, mysql and apache.

i want urls to be more seo/canonicals for my site. i have now:

```
/index.php
/flowers.php?id=41
/flowers.php?type=deco&mode=texture&color=red
etc...
```

is there a way to write something like:

```
/home
/flowers/12
/flowers/deco/texture/red
```

without using .htaccess and mod-rewrite? or i need to look for another hosting?

Comment: I would recommend to enable mod-rewrite, simply open a support ticket to your hosting company to enable it.

Comment: @BookOfZeus I agree. mod-rewrite should be enable , way easy that way

Comment: switch to a better host.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't use a custom method (like the wikipedia for example) you can't. Like @BookOfZeus said, you need to enable mod-rewrite to do so. I would recommend it!

now, here's what you can do:

you have to setup your script to read the URL and then make parse it.

you can have:

> /index.php/page1/page2.html

so the script will read the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] then split in the '/'. so you will an array, then you can do your logic to separate the content.

**if you can**, you can try to hide the PHP by adding this:

```
<Files index>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

so you will endup with a url like: /index/page1/page2.html

source:

http://webarto.com/50/php-seo-url-function

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/95933

Comment: like the idea to force the index to run php.