# Htaccess mod rewrite seo url setup

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site it was runing without seo, I changed links to seo urls.
I create seo links and save them in db.
and usaqe is : seo_url, all fine with php part but having problem with htaccess setup.
I read tons of articles and questions about htaccess setup, and after all I came to this solution which is not working correctly.

need some help espacially in Upanel pagination part. Upanel is a folder.

[closest answer was that one :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977602/making-seo-canonicals-urls-without-mod-rewrite-on-lamp)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^Upanel/?$ Upanel/account.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^Upanel/page/?$ Upanel/account.php?page=$1[L]

RewriteRule ^reset-password/?$ forgot.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^change-password/?$ resetpass.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^user/?$ login.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^hr-search/?$ ik.php [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^sitemap/?$ rss.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ detail.php?p=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ categories.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks for helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all your listed rules, Rewrite condition (RewriteCond) is not needed.

read the comments in the example below.

```
RewriteEngine On
# ^home index.php :request "starts with home"(^home) redirected to index.php,
# [NC,L] search is case insensitive(ie it also matches Home,hOme etc.
# [L] stop processing after this rule.
RewriteRule ^home index.php [NC, L]
# ^Upanel/page/ request starts with Upanel/page/ 
# (.*)$  "everything"(.*) after it "upto end"($) is stored in $1
RewriteRule ^Upanel/page/(.*)$ Upanel/account.php?page=$1 [L]
```

just modified your rules.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^home/ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/ contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/$ Upanel/account.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/page/(.*)$ Upanel/account.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^reset-password/ forgot.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^change-password/ resetpass.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/$ search.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^hr-search/$ ik.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^sitemap/$ rss.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/ detail.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) categories.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

See this.

```
RewriteRule ^Upanel/ Upanel/account.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/page/(.*)$ Upanel/account.php?page=$1 [L]
```

here the second rewriteRule never work because every request which matches second condition also matched by first condition and L flag make sure it stops there at first condition. there for either of the following will work, choose with respect to your requirements.

```
RewriteRule ^Upanel/$ Upanel/account.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/page/(.*)$ Upanel/account.php?page=$1 [L]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^Upanel/page/(.*)$ Upanel/account.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Upanel/ Upanel/account.php [NC,L]
```

see [rewrite rule flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html]) and answrers for [order of rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478346/performance-impact-of-order-of-rewrite-rules-when-using-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: thanks for the answer first , I tried your modified code, but getting error * requested file was not found on this server*. on all urls except detail.php, I am reading your post and trying combinations

Comment: made it work after reading your comments carefully thank you so much, can't give you reputation yet sorry.